# Creating wrapper script for Mail.app to send mail from Terminal

Tags: email, applescript, bash

I'm trying to send mail from terminal with the help of bash and applescript. I use bash for taking care of arguments and the email message body. Then I have tried using Applescript to send the mail with Mail.app. I have run into some problems though, when I try the following I get: `4:4: syntax error: Expected expression but found end of script. (-2741)`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "Arguments: <subject> <recipient>" >&2 #stderr
    exit 1
fi

read message

applescript="
tell application \"Mail\"
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:${1}, content:${message}, address:${2}}
    send theMessage
end tell
"

# send the message
osascript -e ${applescript}
```

**Updated version:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "Arguments: <subject> <recipient>" >&2 #stderr
    exit 1
fi

read message

echo "tell application \"Mail\"
    set theEmail to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:\"${1}\", content:\"${message}\"}
    tell theEmail
        make new recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:\"${2}\"}
        send theEmail
    end tell
end tell" | osascript
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also want to check out this [SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/125707/write-an-email-with-attachment-with-mail-app-from-terminal). The [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/125934) provides a bash script that utilizes AppleScript to send an email with an attachment from a Terminal command line. This script may be more functionality than you need, but it's a great starting point. The code from the answer:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> echo "tell application \"Mail\"
>     activate
>
>     set MyEmail to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:\"$2\", content:\"Some Message Here\"}
>     tell MyEmail
>         make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:\"$1\"}
>         make new attachment with properties {file name:((\"$3\" as POSIX file) as alias)}
>     end tell
> end tell
> " | osascript
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Echoing the string into osascript got rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use Mail.app, or is your goal just to send an email message? If it's just to send an email message from the Terminal, you can use the [sendemail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/) command-line utility.

```
/usr/local/bin/sendemail 
 -f from@my.email.com 
 -t my.recipient@their.email.com 
 -s your.smtp.server:port 
 -xu smtp.username.here 
 -xp smtp.password.here 
 -m message.body.goes.here
```

Obviously in Terminal all of that will need to go on a single line, with appropriate escapes and string quoting. You can look at the man page for sendemail for more options.

Comment: Thanks Ash. I have thought of other options like sendemail, but don't like the idea of storing login details in plain text. After some Googling I found out that there are some options available to use the keychain to authenticate, but there is always some chance of misconfiguration and so on. That is when I thought, hey I already have an authenticated email client: Mail.app, if I could just script that.

Comment: Good point, @foo, I should have mentioned the cleartext login details in my post. That gave me pause too, but I'm using my script to send ToDo emails to Wunderlist using a disposable Gmail account. I don't mind if that account is compromised. I'm glad you found the solution to the problem.